# BigQuery: UNNESTING string representation of list of JSONs

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a STRING column with a LIST [,,] of JSONS that I would like to UNNEST into separate lines.
For example:

```
ROW TICKET_ID Subject      UPDATES(STRING)
1   1         Need help... [{"Actor":"Tom","Type":"Request"}, {"Actor":"John","Type":"Update"}]
2   2         Something... [{"Actor":"Kate","Type":"Request"}, {"Actor":"Tim","Type":"Update"}]
```

I would like it to look like:

```
ROW  TICKET_ID   SUBJECT         UPDATE
 1   1           Need help...    {"Actor":"Tom","Type":"Request"}
 2   1           Need help...    {"Actor":"Tom","Type":"Request"}
 3   2           Something...    {"Actor":"Kate","Type":"Request"}
 4   2           Something...    {"Actor":"Kate","Type":"Request"}
```

I have tried using JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY() and CROSS JOIN UNNEST() so far but unable to split the updates into separate lines as the updates appear as separate rows within the same row (array)

Answer (score 1):

Use below

```
select * except(updates)
from your_table, 
unnest(json_extract_array(updates)) update
```

if applied to sample data in your_question - output is

[image]